# How can I prevent scrolling of container on focus of input?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position

I have a containing div without a vertical scrollbar and an input that is partially visible. When I focus this input the containing div is moved upwards which makes my header disappear partially.

The scenario can be reproduced with the following jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/3gqP9/6/

Is there a solution that keeps the input partially hidden?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do that in chrome. Which browser are you testing on

Comment: I am indeed using Chrome myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. I don't know why you'd want focus on a partially hidden field, but still - adding to the code from your fiddle:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $('#inputField').focus();
   $("#scrollable").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3gqP9/8/

Or you can use `.scrollTop()` (no parameter) to retrieve the scroll position before setting focus and restore it to that same position after calling `.focus()`.

Comment: That only helps so far. Since when I type in the input the same things happen. I guess binding a keydown event to the input and do the scrollTop again would help. But I preferably want to solve this using css rules. This might not be possible though.